# Is there aTwitter Realtime API Like Instagram's?

Tags: php, twitter, instagram, instagram-api

I just got done setting up my website with Instagram's realtime subscriptions. So anytime someone uploads a photo with a certain #hashtag to instagram my server gets notified and my script fetches the photo.

I know Twitter has a streaming API but I don't think it works the same as Instagram's does. I would want my server to be notified of any new tweets with a certain #hashtag. Any information would be very helpful. I'm using php on my server.

Comment: What do you want to do?

Comment: I expect Twitter's dev site contains lots of information about their API. I guess you have to periodically call it with a hashtag search, and identify results you have not seen yet (or supply a time range, perhaps).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Twitter doesn't offer a version of Instagram/Facebook's realtime subscriptions (where they call out to your server). The Streaming APIs are the closest, and require a long-running script on your end.

Comment: So it would probably be more useful to run a cron job every so often on their REST api?

Comment: @ClintC. Depends. We couldn't do that in my last job because it dealt with sweepstakes entries, which we're legally required to ensure we collect all of. Twitter's page says the Search API doesn't necessarily include **all** public posts, so Streaming was our primary option. You may have looser requirements for what you need to pull in.

Comment: We were actually thinking of applying it to contests also. Users can enter via hashtag. I read that the streaming api also didn't show ALL tweets. Did you opt for firehose?

Comment: No one gets Firehose access. Streaming API won't show private tweets, but nothing will show that. It's supposed to show all public tweets reliably as they come in.

Comment: Ok thanks @ceejayoz. Did you use a cronjob for the streaming API or did you just get the latest tweets anytime someone connected to to a page on your site?

Comment: @ClintC. You can't use a cron for the streaming API, it needs to be a continuously running process. We used a PHP script (based on https://github.com/fennb/phirehose) monitored by supervisord.

Comment: Thanks... I 'll check it out.